# Style Text Input As Inline Element (Webkit Only)

Tags: html, forms, css, webkit

I am developing on a webkit javascript application, and trying to find a way to style a text input as if it were a inline span.  The trick is getting the width to only be as large as the text value of the input.  Tried using webkit appearance, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use JavaScript for this. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NMMhs/

Code below:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
   $(this).attr("size",$(this).val().length);
});
```

Comment: The reason why is that the size attribute increments the width of the field only by a fixed amount. For the inverse of W's, try adding !!!s :) There are ways around this, like making the font of the field monospace, etc.

Comment: Well... there is no 3 line limit in answers ;)

Comment: already tried this, unfortunately you need to have a fixed-width font applied to the input.  I ended up going with a span that represent the view state.  I add a data attribute (data-view-element), if the input has that i take the value of the input and store it in the span.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be reasonable for you to use a `span` element and set `contenteditable=true`. You could still assign the content to a hidden input element's value with javascript.

The 'span`could be styled like an inline input field. I think of a border with silghtly rounded corners.

Demo of contenteditable: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable